# Combining Multiple SumIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to combine several accounts using a specific market, X.

How can I simplify the below formula to use an array for the second criteria?

```
=SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A20)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A21)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A22)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A23)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A24)
*SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A25)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A26)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A27)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A28)
*SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A29)
*SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A30)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A31)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A32)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A33)
+SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A34)
*SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A35)
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying some and adding others?

Comment: That was a typo in the formula, meaning to do all "+". However, would like to know how to simplify rather than having such an extensive formula. Is there a shorter equivalent?  @ScottCraner

Comment: I was just waiting to see what you were doing with the `*`

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT() wrapper:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('Report Data'!$H$4:$H$6169,'Report Data'!$E$4:$E$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$3,'Report Data'!$G$4:$G$6169,'SG&A by Spend'!$A$20:$A$35))
```